# estoy empezando con sql y tengo una duda en una practica

Tags: mysql

Tengo que mostrar el nombre de los clientes españoles cuya edad sea superior a la media.

Intento hacerla así pero no me funciona:

```
 SELECT 
   cl.Nombre AS 'Clientes españoles'
FROM 
   clientes cl 
    WHERE
      cl.Pais_nacimiento LIKE 'Esp%'
GROUP BY
     cl.Nombre 
     HAVING
      cl.Fecha_nacimiento<= AVG(cl.Fecha_nacimiento);
```

Esta es la tabla de la base de datos donde hago la consulta :
[image: tabla de la base de datos]

Comment: Muestra el contenido de la tabla _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esto hayque hacer una subconsulta, porque AVG(cl.Fecha_nacimiento) devolverá la media de cada columna (su valor).
Entonces, sería algo tal que:

- Seleccionar todos los datos de los clientes españoles
- El país siempre se llama "España". No hay que usar LIKE, se puede comparar que sean iguales.
- No hay que agruparlos de ninguna forma (GROUP BY)
- Finalmente, añadis otra condición al WHERE (HAVING solo es cuando se agrupa, que no es el caso) comprobando la fecha de nacimiento con el valor que retorne la subconsulta:

  - Seleccionar la fecha de nacimiento media de los clientes

Ahora bien, se presenta otro problema: seleccionar `AVG(Fecha_nacimiento)` devolverá un decimal de la fecha media, por ejemplo `19843882.0000`, de modo que hay que convertir la fecha a número antes de comprobarlo. Para esto, la función `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` es útil, ya que convierte al número de segundos desde el "Unix epoch" (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

De modo que la consulta quedaría algo así:

```sql
SELECT * FROM clientes c 
    WHERE c.Pais_nacimiento = "España"
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Fecha_nacimiento) <
        (SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Fecha_nacimiento)) FROM clientes c2);
```

Comment: la fecha de nacimiento es una fecha.. no es la edad... :/

Comment: @gbianchi y ahi no se interpreta como edad, sino como fecha. Pero en vez de usarla en formato humano, se convierte (año, mes y día) se convierte a milisegundos con respecto a Unix. Pero se sigue respetando la fecha que es, no se está perdiendo precisión (como sería usar solo años).
Por ejemplo 2022-08-26 es 1661464800, y para un mes antes es 1658786400, y la media de estos dos valores sería 1660125600, o 2022-08-10 12:00:00.

Comment: gracias por tu resuesta @ArielCostas , me ha dado la solución a mas de un problema y me ha  ayudado abrir l mente con las siguientes consultas que tenia que realizar .mil gracias